# Having problems with busboy and not finding Content-Type

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, busboy

[image]I'm having hard times with this package of busboy in some app I'm trying to build wanting to upload images from/to my firebase...
Already tried to look at some of your possible solutions with the same problems but perhaps different code and it didn't work.
May I share mine, so you might give me an idea about what is going wrong?
Here the lines:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp()
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const BusBoy = require('busboy')
const fs = require('fs');
const gcConfig = {
    projectId: 'meeting-scheduler-9cee1',
    keyFilename: "meeting-scheduler-9cee1-firebase-adminsdk-3unr4-09df5fe69a.json"
}
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");


exports.upLoadFile = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response,() => {
        const busBoy = new BusBoy({ headers: request.headers});
        let uploadData = null;
        if (request.method !== "POST") {
            return response.status(500).json({
                message: 'Not Allowed!!'
            })
        }

        // if (!request.headers['Content-Type']){
        //     return next(new Error('Bad request'));
        // }
        //   else
        //    next();

        busBoy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
            const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
            uploadData = { file: filepath, type: mimetype };
            file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
        });
        busBoy.on('finish', () => {
            const bucket = gcs.bucket('meeting-scheduler-9cee1.appspot.com');
            bucket
                .upload(uploadData.file, {
                    uploadType: 'media',
                    metadata: {
                        metadata: {
                            contentType: uploadData.type
                        }
                    }
                })
                .then(() => {
                    response.status(200).json({
                        message: 'It Works!'
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {

                    response.status(500).json({
                        error: err
                    })
                })
    });
    busBoy.end(request.rawBody);


});

});
```

Any time I fire the function in my firebase de error is the same,I'm sharing it too:

```
Error: Missing Content-Type
    at new Busboy (/srv/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:23:11)
    at cors (/srv/index.js:58:24)
    at cors (/srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
    at /srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
    at originCallback (/srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
    at /srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
    at optionsCallback (/srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
    at corsMiddleware (/srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
    at exports.upLoadFile.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:57:5)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:49:9)
```

Comment: Side note: You should use `if (request.method !== "POST") { return response.status(405).set('Allow', 'POST').json({ message: 'Not Allowed!!' }) }`

Comment: Can you share your client code where you are making the request?

Comment: Also, don't forget to handle errors from `cors` using `cors(request, response, (err) => { if (err) { /* do something */ return; } /* ... */ })`

Comment: Lastly, rather than use `busBoy.end(request.rawBody);`, use `request.pipe(busBoy);` for better performance

Comment: ok i already add the request made through postman, and tried to apply your advices on my code, but still doesnt work

Comment: Those were just other points to tidy up your code. Can you expand the "temporary headers" and response headers in that image?

Comment: Can you move `const busBoy = new BusBoy({ headers: request.headers});` down below the `if (request.method !== "POST") { /* ... */ }`? You shouldn't be trying to initialise it on a non-POST request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ran into this myself. Turns out, main.js in the busboy module checks for `content-type` instead of `Content-Type`, and thus does not find the header. Confirmed this was the issue by fixing the casing in main.js (which isn't a feasible solution in most cases), after which the constructor call worked on my request, as expected.

Apparently this was brought up before, but the issue was closed ([link](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy/issues/210)).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using `postman` and encounters this issue: I didn't realize the file postman was referencing no longer existed, thus `content-type` didn't exist, but `postman` never complained. I switched to a valid file and it worked.

Comment: Even though the file still exists I had to select again to work.

Answer (score 0):

As Kacey pointed out, busboy throws this error because the HTTP request does not contain a `Content-Type` header.

HTTP headers are by default written in lowercase once it reaches Node, no matter how you might have defined them in the frontend for instance, hence causing this error.

I solved it by simply adding the following lines to my code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = req.headers['content-type']; next();
})
app.use(busboy());
```